# Periodically recreating an Object

Tags: java, spring, jakarta-ee, spring-mvc, singleton

I'm trying to integrate my service to another service ( Service B). In order to create a client for service B, I need to get a Token and use it while I create the client. The token expires every 72 hours. Once the token expires, the client also expires. So I need to recreate the client.

Right now, the client object is a Singleton, instantiated by Spring during start up. I want to recreate this object every 72 hours.

I'm thinking of using the singleton, with synchronized getInstance. Is there a better way to do this?

Comment: Change the scope of the bean from `@Singleton` to `@Prototype` and let Spring create the new instance of the bean every 72 hours.

Comment: how do we control the 72 hour aspect in spring? I can define the bean as prototype, which will create it every time its invoked. but, I want it to be created only every 72 hours.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Singleton would be there best way to do this. When you get your token, save a static timestamp variable for the time when you got the token. Then, in your `getInstance()` function, check the timestamp against the current time to see if it is more than 72 hours old. If it is, grab a new token and recreate the instance before you return it, if it is not, just return the instance.

I've done something similar using OAuth authentication, and found it to be a simple and effective method.

Answer (score 1):

If you want new instance of the client object every time you requested then change the scope of the spring bean from singleton to prototype. Container will create a new instance of the object each time you requested.

Also you can use quartz scheduler and create a job for recreating the object (actually asking new reference from spring container) with repeat interval as 72 hours. You can easily integrate quartz with spring by following these [instructions](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/4.0.4.RELEASE/spring-framework-reference/htmlsingle/#scheduling-quartz)

Comment: I couldn't find any official documentation of quartz integration with spring 3.x and because of that I provided 1.x documentation link. The steps are almost same for both the versions.

Comment: How about a even fresher documentation: [Using the Quartz Scheduler](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/4.0.4.RELEASE/spring-framework-reference/htmlsingle/#scheduling-quartz).

Comment: It will definitely help. Thanks for sharing!